# How to use the results of a dynamic Top N filter on one worksheet as the filter on another worksheet

Tags: tableau-api

I have a very small workbook [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7dgw1w3fFPwOHRJazduN3ZqNzQ) that helps explain the use case. This workbook is drawing data of video game sales.

Basically the idea is that I have 2 worksheets. One worksheet takes the top N video game developers by sales (and the N is fed through a parameter), and there is a genre quick filter, which is used in-context (so every time you change the genre, the top N developers will recalculate). Pretty cool.

Then there is a second worksheet. All I want is the top N developers from the first worksheet to be used on the second worksheet as well, and their sales breakdown by ALL genres. This is almost impossible to do, it seems, because by default the 2nd worksheet can only satisfy 1 of 2 criteria:

1. Calculate the top N developers by selected genres
2. Show the sales breakdown of those top N developers by ALL genres

**I can't do both of these at the same time, only one at a time.** Headscratching, really. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I got around a similar problem by using the RANK function to assign a score to each of the genres, then filter on the rank. As you are filtering on rank this should be persistent and update dynamically as per your filtered data.

Ben